# Running maven project on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm using tomcat 7 and when I run my web application(maven project), it gives me this error:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:hr_demo-security-context.xml]
```

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

hr_demo-security-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you show the complete content of hr_demo-security-context.xml ?

Comment: it is the complete content. thats all i have in hr_demo-security.xml

Answer (score 0):

There is `syntax` problem with your `hr_demo-security-context.xml`.

Comment: how to open this file? i try to search it but cant find it

Comment: the you probably forgot to create it. check where it is referenced and change the reference to your correct context definition or create a new one

Comment: <i found, it contains the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
 xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

Comment: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

</beans:beans>

Comment: i cant post it. :( it tells me the answer looks like spam!

Answer (score 0):

Either your in-code reference to the XML file is no longer referencing the file after deployment (due to the file being moved after packaging) or the xml file you have posted is being referenced, but by having no entries within it Spring is getting confused.